# ng --version pops the VS code instead of giving the version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After installing the Angular globally using this command

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

When I try checking
`ng --version`

VS code pops up with ng.js file.

What does this mean?

Is anything wrong with my installation?

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine try doing it in the cmd outside of vs-code, if it works change from powershell to CMD in vscode.